# I can't add data more than 3 to hazelcast image cluster with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, hazelcast

I have a docker image running in my local. I can add and get 3 data with key to the cluster. But I take an error at forth data.

[image]

And my code is here.

```
    var map = {};
    var hazelCastRequest = function (key) {
        HazelcastClient
            .newHazelcastClient(config)
            .then((hazelcastClient) => {
                map = hazelcastClient.getMap(mapName).then(function (mp) {
                    map = mp;
                    if(reqType=="post"){
                         insertPerson(map, key);
                    }
                    if(reqType=="get"){
                        readPerson(map, key);
                    }
                });
            }).catch( function (error){
                console.log("clientErrorDeneme", error);
            });};   
    hazelCastRequest(key);

    var printValue = function (text, value) {
        console.log(text + JSON.stringify(value));
    };

    var insertPerson = function (map, key) {
        var person = {}
        if (key == "key1") {
            person = {
                key: key,firstName: "Joe",lastName: "Doe",age: 42
            };}
    
        map.put(key, person).then(function (previousValue) {
            printValue("Previous value: ", previousValue);
        }).catch( function (error){
            console.log("error1", error);
        });
    };

    var readPerson = function (map, key) {
        map.get(key).then(function (value) {
            printValue("Value for key=1: ", value);
            printedValue=value.key;
        }).catch( function (error){
            console.log("error2", error);
        });
    };
server.listen(7001);
```

Also my debug console error is that in vscode.

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Logged error messages make me thinking that there is a connectivity issue and the client can't connect to the cluster member for some reasons.

If you think it's an issue related with the client itself, could you create a GH issue with a reproducer for the issue?
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-nodejs-client/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new connection `HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config)` and a `getMap` every time you want to insert or read. `HazelcastClient.getMap(...)` is a remote operation and adds to the latency of cache operation. Instead, make the connection with servers once, get the desired map from server once and reuse the reference to the map for all subsequent operations.